# problem with auto-created bigquery field name that contains "."

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, etl, quickbooks-online

I used a simple ETL tool to import QuickBooks data into Google BigQuery.  Great!  The only challenge notable limitation on this step is that I can't do any translation ... more like it's an EL tool.

That said, now I want to query the imported table.  It's no problem at all for correctly named fields in BigQuery (like `txndate`).  However, some of the fields are of the format `abc.xyz` (e.g., `deposittoaccountref.value`) and can't be queried.  The "." in the name is apparently confusing BigQuery.

If I dump the whole table, I can see the "." name fields and the associated values.

However, I can't create a custom query against those fields.  They don't show up in the auto-generated schema that allows one to drag and drop field names into the query.

Also, I tried to manually type the field name in and received the following error message: `Missing column alias. Any expression in a SELECT statement that is not a column from the original data source must be followed by an alias, for example: AS my_alias`.

I've tried quoting the field name and bracketing the field name but they still throw the same error.

I traced back to QB API documentation and this is indeed how Intuit labels the fields.

Finally, as long as I can query these fields at all, I can rename them to eliminate the `"."` problem.

Please advise and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ok, I solved this myself.

The way to fix this within bigquery query editor is to manually type in the field name (i.e., not available in the auto-generated schema) and to parenthesis the field name.

e.g, deposittoaccountref.value becomes (deposittoaccountref.value)

Now, this will label the column in the result set as "value", so you may want to relabel the data field to something without the ".".  For example, I took the original
deposittoaccountref.value and modified it to
(deposittoaccountref.value) as deposittoaccountref_value

Hopefully, this will help someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

the above answer works when there is a single dot in the name as in the example.

however, if there are multiple e.g., "line.value.amount" then the parenthesis trick doesn't work

i've tried nesting the parenthesis in different ways to no avail
e.g., (line.value.amount) = error error, ((line.value).amount) = error, (line.(value.amount)) = error